# Use of unlimited polymorphic type for array operation in Fortran 03/08 (gfortran compiler)

Tags: arrays, class, fortran, gfortran

I'd like to realize useful array operations (add element, remove element, different realizations by allocatable/pointer/binary tree structures) by `class(*)` feature (unlimited polymorphism). I use gfortran 5.0 that should handle such a feature. I need it for not repeating identical code for each type I use.

This should look something like

```
function add_element(array,element)
  class(*),intent(in)::array(:)
  class(*),intent(in)::element
  class(*)::add_element(size(array)+1)
       add_element=[array,element]
end function
```

The problem is that when I try to use this function with some definite type, I have an error with returning result. I can not assign `class(*)` to some definite type variable without `select type`, and I surely don't want to have select type structures every time I use it. And inside a subroutine I should not know anything of types I want to use, because I will create many of them.

I tried some variants with `move_alloc`, source, tried to use subroutine with `intent(out)` argument etc. It didn't work. I think it should be defined in argument attributes, the same as size (with source keyword?) but didn't find an example or a definition of such structure in standard. Of course I will study this standard more (I'm not a professional programmer but physicist trying to make my programs testable, checkable and more comfortable to change) and will simply repeat this code now in waiting for better solution, but maybe anybody knows where to search it in the standard or some book? I think this is not only about arrays but use of `class(*)` at all as I think there should be methods that don't know of types...

Don't know if I should add examples of other not working forms of this subroutine or what it says about the error - or a question will be unfocused. It can be compiled, but in all cases assigning to definite type in call doesn't work. For argument `intent(out)` or `(inout)` it can not go from dummy argument to actual argument. Reallocation from source makes an object which has type (and a result of assigning in my example too), but the type is hidden... and I can't use the select type in subroutine because I don't know the type.

Also I don't know constructs that could check "the same type as" or something in this context...

Answer (score 5):

This is not an easy problem You can use `select type`, but Fortran doesn't have anything like `type is(type_of(x))`. On the other hand, there are the `SAME_TYPE_AS()` and `EXTENDS
TYPE_OF()` intrinsics, but you cannot use them as type guards.

It is necessary to assure, that the dynamic types of both `array` and `element` are the same.

I think this is a deficiency in the standard.

But still, there is an error in your approach. You should make the function result allocatable, to be able to allocate it to correct dynamic type:

`class(*), allocatable ::add_element(:)`

You may think something along the lines of: (UNTESTED! compiles with gfortran-4.9 ifort14)

`allocate(add_element(size(array)+1), mold=array)`

But how to actually transfer the values I don't know and I am worried it might not be possible without resorting to some dirty tricks.

You cannot even use `transfer` and that is where I see real deficiency. Eventhough you can call transfer with polymorphic mold

```
transfer(element, add_element(1))
```

you have no way to assign it to the array element

```
add_element(1) = transfer(element, add_element(1))
```

My opinion is that Fortran lacks an option for the type guards that just ensures that two variables have the same dynamic type.

You may think something along the lines of: (UNTESTED! compiles with gfortran-4.9 ifort14)

```
function add_element(array,element)
  use iso_c_binding
  implicit none
  class(*),intent(in)::array(:)
  class(*),intent(in)::element
  class(*), allocatable ::add_element(:)
  type(c_ptr) :: tmp

  interface
    function memcpy(dest, src, n) bind(c)
      use iso_c_binding
      integer(c_intptr_t),value :: dest, src
      integer(c_size_t) :: n
      type(c_ptr) :: memcpy
    end function
  end interface

  allocate(add_element(size(array)+1), mold=array)

  tmp = memcpy(loc(add_element(size(array)+1)), &
               loc(array), &
               size(array, kind=c_size_t) * storage_size(array, c_size_t)/8_c_size_t )
  tmp = memcpy(loc(add_element(size(array)+1)), &
               loc(array(1)), &
               storage_size(element, c_size_t)/8_c_size_t )

end function
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer! I thought that it is a problem of standard, but it is like not using class(*) at all, waiting for new standard versions - I don't know how it can be used without result returning.

Comment: You CAN return class(*) in Fortran! The problem is in setting the value.

Comment: I tried variant with allocation, it's only without it for simplicity and because I prefer to check array dimensions if could - such construction is possible for usual types. But allocatable with moving allocation returns the same... <br> And of course I should prefer to check types of arguments but don't know how, I remembered same_type_as but it can not return what I need. <br> I don't know C for your example and the part of standard that uses C binding (I deferred it for the time it will be necessary...) but I will try to think of it, thanks.

Comment: I mean to return class(*) to definite-type variable... If I use allocation with source, the hidden type will be right if I undestand it right... problem with a procedure/function call

Comment: Thats true, you have to return `class(*), allocatable ` and return a polymorphic result in any case. In the calling code you need to use `select type `.

Answer (score 4):

CLASS(*) is a facility that basically allows runtime type safe but type agnostic storage.  You are trying to use it as a compile time type parameterisation mechanism.  It isn't terribly appropriate for that, and the language doesn't directly support an alternative means.

Traditionally type parameterisation is done by placing the common parts of the procedures to be parameterised in a separate file, and then including that file as appropriate, perhaps in a module that uses implicit typing to specify the type to be parameterised.

If you must use CLASS(*), you practically need to write and use a wrapper type.  If all you are wrapping is basic array operations, then this will be far more trouble than it is worth.

In client code (versus your common procedures) to extract the thing that has been stored you generally need to use SELECT TYPE (you can use pointer assignment if the type of the data has BIND(C) or SEQUENCE, but this isn't type safe).

```
TYPE :: Wrapper
  CLASS(*), ALLOCATABLE :: item
END TYPE Wrapper

FUNCTION add_element(array, element)
  TYPE(Wrapper), INTENT(IN) :: array(:)
  CLASS(*), INTENT(IN) :: element
  TYPE(Wrapper), INTENT(OUT) :: add_element(SIZE(array)+1)
  ! If you want to enforce type consistency (at runtime)...
  IF (SIZE(array) > 0) THEN
    IF (.NOT. SAME_TYPE_AS(array(1)%item, element)) THEN
      STOP 'Objects not of same type!'
    END IF
  END IF
  add_element(:SIZE(array)) = array
  add_element(SIZE(add_element))%item = element
END FUNCTION add_element

FUNCTION get(scalar)
  TYPE(Wrapper), INTENT(IN) :: scalar
  CLASS(*), ALLOCATABLE :: get
  get = scalar%item
END FUNCTION get

...

TYPE(Wrapper), ALLOCATABLE :: array(:)
array = [ Wrapper :: ]
array = add_element(array, 'cat')
array = add_element(array, 'dog')

DO i = 1, SIZE(array)
  SELECT TYPE (item => get(array(i)))
  TYPE IS (CHARACTER(*))
    PRINT "(A)", item
  END SELECT
END DO
```

Comment: I wouldn't say he tries parametric polymorphism. To me it seems more similar to classical type-less polymorphism of C (like in memcpy and many other generic functions). What you suggest is the opposite he does, he has normal data and tries to cope up with a generic procedure to cope with them. You create a new datatype which does not help in this problem (e.g.add an element to an array of integers or an array of reals or of some type(x)).

Comment: I leave it to the OP to clarify, but there's mention in the question about "repeating identical code" for different types.  That's a reasonable symptom of a need for generic programming (type parameterisation or parametric polymorphism or whatever term you want to use).  `CLASS(*)` offers generic storage/reference capability but not the capability for generic operations.  Using `CLASS(*)` and encapsulating generic operations practically requires a wrapper type.  The alternative is to use INCLUDE/IMPLICIT tricks.  In Fortran 95 you could maybe get away with memcpy/TRANSFER, but not in F2003!